# Delphi - How can I pass Generic parameter to function that accept Array of const parameter

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe4

I have a 'Base class' which contain a 'function' that accept parameter of type 'Array of const' as shown below:-

```
type
  TBaseClass = class(TObject)
  public
    procedure NotifyAll(const AParams: array of const);
  end;

procedure TBaseClass.NotifyAll(const AParams: array of const);
begin
  // do something
end;
```

I have another 'Generic class' that is derived from the 'base class' ( defined above )

```
type
  TEventMulticaster<T> = class(TBaseClass)
  public
    procedure Notify(AUser: T); reintroduce;
  end;

procedure TEventMulticaster<T>.Notify(AUser: T);
begin
  inherited NotifyAll([AUser]);   ERROR HERE
end;
```

Every time I compile this code it gives error saying:

> Bad argument type in variable type array constructor

What does it referring to be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass a Generic argument as a [variant open array parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Variant_Open_Array_Parameters). The language Generics support simply does not cater for that.

What you can do instead is wrap the Generic argument in a variant type, for instance `TValue`. Now, you cannot pass `TValue` instances in a variant open array parameter either, but you can change `NotifyAll()` to accept an open array of `TValue` instead:

```
procedure NotifyAll(const AParams: array of TValue);
```

Once you have this in place, you can call it from your Generic method like so:

```
NotifyAll([TValue.From<T>(AUser)]);
```

Fundamentally, what you are attempting to do here is combine compile-time parameter variance (Generics) with run-time parameter variance. For the latter, there are various options. Variant open array parameters are one such option, but they do not play well with Generics. The alternative that I suggest here, `TValue`, does have good interop with Generics.

Comment: The `NotifyAll(const AParams: array of TValue)` could be declared as `overload` to handle both concepts in the base class as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Rtti` unit has something exactly for you needs, but not widely known:

[`TValueArrayToArrayOfConst()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TValueArrayToArrayOfConst) and
[`ArrayOfConstToTValueArray()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.ArrayOfConstToTValueArray)

So your implementation should be:

```pascal
procedure TEventMulticaster<T>.Notify(AUser: T);
var
  ParametersAsTValueArray: array[1 .. 1] of TValue;
begin
  ParametersAsTValueArray[1] := TValue.From<T>(AUser);
  NotifyAll(TValueArrayToArrayOfConst(ParametersAsTValueArray));
end;
```

Notes:

1. `TValueArrayToArrayOfConst()`'s result is a non-owning container. It contains memory pointers backed by the source array of the `TValue` container. `ParametersAsTValueArray` is alive and not being altered while the `array of const` is used.
2. One of these 2 `Rtti` procedures has a bug with regard to `TClass` values processing. `TClass` becomes a `Pointer` on some stage, and `string.Format()` breaks because `Pointer` and `TClass` are not the same thing. Perform tests on all `TVarRec.VType`, they are not so many, much less that Variant's `VType`.