# Generics and Array of const

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe4

```
type
  TGeneric<T> = class(TBase)
  public
    procedure Swap(Harry : T);
    procedure NotifyAll(AParams : T); 
  end;
```

i have two question

1. Is there any way i can typecast a generic variable in any other type like variant etc.
2. how can i pass generic type in function that accept array of const like here

   [Delphi - How can I pass Generic parameter to function that accept Array of const parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584559/delphi-how-can-i-pass-generic-parameter-to-function-that-accept-array-of-const)

Comment: Hi John, ideally you would ask two questions

Comment: both questions are related so i asked them here not separately .

Comment: You already linked the answer to question 2 or am I missing something here?

Comment: What is a generic variable? Could you give us some example code?

Comment: TGeneric<T> = class (tbase)
    public
      procedure Swap(harry : T);
    procedure NotifyAll( AParams : T);
   end;                                                                  here harry is generic variable that can accept any type

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem? (BTW: You should edit your question instead of posting the code as a comment, I did that for you this time)

Comment: i am working on legacy code and i am trying to use generics to reduce code size , So i want to pass a generic type to a function that accepts array of const parameter as shown in link i gave in my question but the answer of that question says use tvalue instead of const but if i do this it beaks many other part of my code all i am asking is there any other way to implements this kind of functionality .

Comment: If that really is your question then this is a duplicate. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can typecast a generic variable in any other type like `Variant` etc.

As stated in my answer to the question you link, the variant type that works well with generics is `TValue`. You can make a `TValue` instance from a generic type using the `From` method:

```
procedure TMyClass.Foo<T>(const Item: T);
var
  Value: TValue;
begin
  Value := TValue.From<T>(Item);
end;
```

> How can I pass generic type in function that accept `array of const`?

This is the exact same question that was asked in the [question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26584559/). The answer is the same as stated there, namely that you cannot pass a generic argument as a [variant open array parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Variant_Open_Array_Parameters). Again, `TValue` to the rescue. Instead of using a variant open array parameter, use an open array of `TValue`.

---

The bottom line here is that the variant type that works well with generics, and that is supplied with the Delphi RTL, is `TValue`.

Comment: if i use tvalue it breaks lots of other parts of my code that is why i am avoiding it

Comment: You are going to have to accept that you cannot pass a generic argument as a variant open array parameter.

Comment: can i typecast it in some other type then sent it, but not Tvalue

Comment: You keep asking, but my answer is the same. Use `TValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Copying my code from linked question:

```
procedure TEventMulticaster<T>.Notify(AUser: T);
var
  ParametersAsTValueArray: array[1 .. 1] of TValue;
begin
  ParametersAsTValueArray[1] := TValue.From<T>(AUser);
  NotifyAll(TValueArrayToArrayOfConst(ParametersAsTValueArray));
end;
```